# Service value is not modified after event click

Tags: angular

I'm using service to share values between 2 components. I display this value in one and want to change it in the other by clicking on a button. The problem is that the value is not modified. I know that I have some problems to understand some concepts. Can anyone help me . Thanks

dataservice.service.ts

```
export class DataserviceService {

  sharedValue=3;
  modifiedValue = 0;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
   }

   changeData(){
    this.modifiedValue++;
   }

   retrieveData(){
    return this.modifiedValue;
  }


}
```

compo2.component.ts

```
export class Compo2Component implements OnInit {


  constructor(private datas:DataserviceService) {

   }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  shareData(){

    this.datas.changeData();  

  }

}
```

compo2.component.html

```
<button (click)="shareData()">Click here</button>
```

get.component.ts

```
export class GetComponent implements OnInit {

  data:number;
  constructor(private datas:DataserviceService ){


  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.data = this.datas.retrieveData();
    console.log(this.data);

  }

}
```

When I  executed the fonction to modify the value  into constructor, the value is modified but when I  try to use it with a click event it doesn't work.

Comment: You can't use statefull services in Angular with much luck. You should use observables instead

Comment: @TheProcess in app.module.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use observables, somthing like this:

```
export class DataserviceService {
  sharedValue=3;
  modifiedValue = 0;

  private modifiedValue : BehaviorSubject<number>;
  constructor() {
    this.modifiedValueSubject = new BehaviorSubject(this.modifiedValue);
  }
  changeData(){
    this.modifiedValue++;
    this.modifiedValueSubject.next(this.modifiedValue);
  }
  retrieveData(): Observable<number>{
     return this.modifiedValueSubject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

then in your components ngOnInit subscribe to that observable:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.datas.retrieveData().subscribe(data =>{
    this.data = data;
    console.log(data);
 });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you a lot @KavehG. Can you explain me why  we have to used Observable. What's the concept behind that.

Comment: That's because in your code the modifiedValue  is assigned to the property just once in the OnInit function, further that the value is changed the property is not. you have to use an observable which emits the data changes , and subscribe to its changes, so that on every change you update the property inside your component.